# autocmd: match more than one pattern

Tags: autocmd

I want to write an `autocmd` `pat` that matches more than one file, eg:

```
" Source .vimrc after saving
autocmd! BufWritePost ($MYVIMRC,$MYGVIMRC) nested source % | echom "Reloaded " . expand('%') | redraw
```

`:help pat` doesn't give examples around the usage of `(`, `{`, `|` and `,`

How do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC,$MYGVIMRC {cmd....}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use escaped parenthesis and escaped `|` sign as a delimiter, like so:

```
" Source .vimrc after saving
autocmd! BufWritePost \($MYVIMRC\|$MYGVIMRC\) CMD
```